# How do you specify output log file using structlog?

Tags: python, logging, logfile, structlog

I feel like this should be super simple but I cannot figure out how to specify the path for the logfile when using structlog. The [documentation](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html) states that you can use traditional logging alongside structlog so I tried this:

```
    logger = structlog.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile_path, level=logging.ERROR)
    logger.error("TEST")
```

The log file gets created but of course "TEST" doesn't show up inside it. It's just blank.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? If so, can you tell me how please?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get an example working by [following the docs](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging) to log to both stdout and a file.

```
import logging.config
import structlog

timestamper = structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso")
logging.config.dictConfig({
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "handlers": {
            "default": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            },
            "file": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
                "filename": "test.log",
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                "handlers": ["default", "file"],
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "propagate": True,
            },
        }
})
structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        timestamper,
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)
structlog.get_logger("test").info("hello")
```

If if you just wanted to log to a file you could use the snippet hynek suggested.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score -2):

For structlog log entries to appear in that file, you have to tell structlog to use stdlib logging for output. You can find three different approaches in the [docs](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#suggested-configurations), depending on your other needs.

Comment: Can you please detail your answer? I still can't seem to figure it out and couldn't find what I need from the documentation as it seems quite complicated.

Comment: The problem is that standard library logging *is* complicated. If you insist on using it, you'll have to spend some time learning it. The easiest way as of structlog 22.1 is to use [`structlog.stdlib.recreate_defaults(log_level=None)`](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.stdlib.recreate_defaults) which will configure structlog to log thru stdlib and then use something like `logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)` to configure logging.

Comment: thanks! it works but the printing doesn't look as good as it did in the console:
`[2m2022-08-12 14:08.49[0m [[32m[1minfo     [0m] [1mHello, world![0m`
whereas on the console things look like:
`2022-08-11 23:30.25 [info     ] Executing step                 step=99`

Comment: That is because the logs are outputted to the console with colors, but your console does not support colors. You can disable colored logs in console by setting:

```python3
structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(colors=False)
```